# Create a new row for each day between dates from two different columns in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift, recursive-query

I am working with a table in Redshift. It contains rows with some information and two dates (a start date and an end date). I can't seem to be able to figure out a way to create a new row for each day between the start and end date. For example, here the code to make a simple table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dates (name VARCHAR(50), start_date DATETIME, end_date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO dates
VALUES
       ('Peter F.','2018-03-01','2018-03-05'),
       ('Sam R.','2018-04-17', '2018-04-20');

SELECT * FROM dates;
```

How do I go from

```
name          | start_date                | end_date                   | 
Peter F.      | 2018-04-17 00:00:00.000000| 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000 |
Sam R.        | 2018-03-01 00:00:00.000000| 2018-03-05 00:00:00.000000 |
```

to:

```
name          | start_date                | end_date                   | 
Peter F.      | 2018-04-17 00:00:00.000000| 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000 |
Peter F.      | 2018-04-18 00:00:00.000000| 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000 |
Peter F.      | 2018-04-19 00:00:00.000000| 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000 |
Peter F.      | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000| 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000 |
Sam R.        | 2018-03-01 00:00:00.000000| 2018-03-05 00:00:00.000000 |
Sam R.        | 2018-03-02 00:00:00.000000| 2018-03-05 00:00:00.000000 |
Sam R.        | 2018-03-03 00:00:00.000000| 2018-03-05 00:00:00.000000 |
Sam R.        | 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000000| 2018-03-05 00:00:00.000000 |
Sam R.        | 2018-03-05 00:00:00.000000| 2018-03-05 00:00:00.000000 |
```

I tried using a recursive CTE like this:

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT name,
                start_date,
                end_date
         FROM   dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT name,
                Dateadd(day, 1, start_date),
                end_date
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  start_date < end_date)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```

But it gives me an error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "cte" does not exist;
```

Hoping for some expert advice, as I'd really like to be able to do this in SQL... Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift does not support recursive common table expressions.

One approach is to build a table of numbers:

```
create table nums(n int);
insert into nums values(0), (1), (2), (3), ...
```

You can then join the numbers table with the original table to generate the expected result:

```
select
    d.name,
    dateadd(day, n.n, d.start_date) start_date,
    d.end_date
from dates d
inner join nums n 
    on dateadd(day, n.n, d.start_date) <= d.end_date
```

You can also list the numbers as a derived table directly in your query, or use `row_number()` against a large table.

Comment: Thank you a ton, @GBM! This works perfectly. I guess I would thing is I would need to generate a table with a long column of numbers, to ensure it always works? Sometimes my dates are a year or two apart. Any suggestions on how to make this more maintainable?

Comment: @Georgiy: yes you need as many numbers as there may be days between your dates... You can generate the list of `insert`s for the table of numbers programatically with the tool of your choice. Alternatively, you can use `row_number()` against a large table, like: `insert into numbers select row_number() over() from mylargetable`.

Comment: Thank you, @GBM , I appreciate all your help!

Comment: hey @GMB, how to list numbers directly as a derived table in query? Our client don't want us to create any new number table or calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here - the first is how to create the range of dates table to join with your start and end dates.  The trick with Redshift is to not rely on creating a sequence.  You can make a sequence fairly easily with a little cross joining.

```
create table ten (X) as select values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);
create table (X) thousand as 
select C.X * 100 + B.X * 10 + A.X from ten A
cross join ten B
cross join ten C;
```

You can expand this up to any order of magnitude you like and convert it to days.  (from memory so I'll apologize if I made any typos)

GMB gives a good example of how to create copies of all the rows for all the dates between  start and end date.  This is can be a good way to go for small numbers of rows in your, let me guess, accounts table but since you are specifically talking about Redshift there's a good chance that this table is quite large.  Replicating a large table by the number of days between start and end date will result in a very large data product this will be slow to create and take lots of spill to disk.  This is problem #2 (again assuming you have a heck of a lot of accounts).

If this is the case then may I suggest a different approach.  Union-ing you accounts table with itself and the numbers table converted to dates will give you very date and when each account starts and ends. With some windowing you can find most summaries that you are likely looking for and won't need to make massive data images to do it.  To be clear this pays off big time the bigger the table is but for small tables the the joining method will be best.  (2N method vs. N times Dates)

Comment: Thank you for the info! I have one table in the format I described that I needed to expand only based on the dates, and I haven't been able to make it work in a different way. If you could provide another code example to solve the problem of expanding table - I'd be grateful.

Comment: So the idea is to not create the expanded table.  The question is what end are you trying to achieve by created the expanded table?  In most cases you can generate the result you are looking for without multiplying out copies of the rows.  A common case is producing a table of number of active accounts by day.  Is this the kind of thing you are making?  If so I can post an answer along those lines

Comment: I have other tables that are in this expanded format, and I need to join them using some keys and the dates. The thing is, these tables may not necessarily have a time stamp for each day between `start_date` and `end_date` in the LEFT table, and in that case I still need the date, but with nulls coming from the LEFT JOIN on these other tables. Does that make sense? I couldn't see a different way of doing it

Comment: In other words, image the first table I provided as the example being the LEFT table. Then, on the right, I have a table like the second one I used in my example, but there isn't a row for every date in `start_date` column between the start and end date. However, when I join these two tables, I want to have a row for each date in `start_date` even if it didn't exist in the second table (which, in case of a LEFT join, will just result in NULL values).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte("range_date", "start_date", "end_date") AS (
    SELECT
          sysdate::date AS "range_date"
        , sysdate::date AS "start_date"
        , DATEADD(DAY, 10, sysdate::date)::date AS "end_date"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          DATEADD(DAY, 1, range_date)::date AS range_date
        , start_date
        , end_date
    FROM cte
    WHERE cte.range_date < cte.end_date
)
SELECT cte.range_date FROM cte
```

Comment: There is a comment on adding no tables...